# DELETE using LEFT JOIN with LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to delete orphan posts in my database and I have created this query:

```
DELETE post.*
      FROM foro_post AS post
      LEFT JOIN foro_thread AS thread USING(threadid)
      WHERE thread.threadid IS NULL
```

The problem is that I want to limit because my table has over 7,000,000 records.

As I can't use LIMIT with the query, I tried this and actually worked, but I'm not sure if is an efficient solution or if it could be done better.

```
DELETE post.*
      FROM foro_post AS post
      LEFT JOIN foro_thread AS thread USING(threadid)
      WHERE thread.threadid IS NULL
      AND post.postid < 500

      // Where < 500 should be increasing as I delete records
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: @njk "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 5" Apparently can't use LIMIT with LEFT JOIN

Comment: In similar cases you should consider to use a foreign key with some constraint.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't use `LIMIT` directly within [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) when you're referencing multiple tables at the same time, but you can get around that by encasing what you want to delete within a subselect:

```
DELETE po 
FROM   foro_post po
JOIN   (
       SELECT    p.postid
       FROM      foro_post p
       LEFT JOIN foro_thread t ON p.threadid = t.threadid
       WHERE     t.threadid IS NULL
       ORDER BY  p.postid
       LIMIT     50
       ) pp ON po.postid = pp.postid
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what would be "p.id"? I'm fairly new to MySQL

Comment: @Santiago, that's just the primary key of the `post` table. I now see that it's `postid` instead of `id`, adjusting my solution now.

Comment: @zane-bien You can use `LIMIT` directly, just not in multi-table syntax.

Comment: I see Zane. Also is "foro_post", and in ORDER BY it's still "p.id". But even correcting all that, I get this: Unknown column 'p' in 'field list'

Comment: @Santiago that's weird that shouldn't happen. Perhaps the table alias `p` was conflicting with the alias in the subselect (which normally it shouldn't). Try it now with my latest edit.

Comment: I tried your last edit but I still get the same error. Maybe it has something to do that I want to test it using SELECT instead of DELETE first? This is what I'm doing:  `SELECT po 
FROM   foro_post po
JOIN   (
       SELECT    p.postid
       FROM      foro_post p
       LEFT JOIN foro_thread t ON p.threadid = t.threadid
       WHERE     t.threadid IS NULL
       ORDER BY  p.postid
       LIMIT     50
       ) pp ON po.postid = pp.postid`

Comment: I think I get it. I'm now using `SELECT po.*` and getting 50 results. Should I use `DELETE po.*` or just `DELETE po`to delete this records from foro_post?

Comment: @Santiago, you shouldn't have to use * (that's just supported for "compatibility with Access"), but try it anyway with `po.*`.

Comment: You can also use a natural join for the delete query if you have a complicated primary key.