# subquery in FROM must have an alias

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, subquery

I have this query I have written in PostgreSQL that returns an error saying:

> [Err] ERROR:
>   LINE 3: FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (identifiant) AS made_only_recharge

This is the whole query:

```
SELECT COUNT (made_only_recharge) AS made_only_recharge
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (identifiant) AS made_only_recharge
    FROM cdr_data
    WHERE CALLEDNUMBER = '0130'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT (identifiant) AS made_only_recharge
    FROM cdr_data
    WHERE CALLEDNUMBER != '0130'
)
```

I have a similar query in Oracle that works fine. The only change is where I have `EXCEPT` in Oracle I have replaced it with the `MINUS` key word. I am new to Postgres and don't know what it is asking for. What's the correct way of handling this?

Comment: It looks to me the exception is unnecessary as the first where clause already excepts it: `CALLEDNUMBER = '0130'`.

Comment: This error still happens with Postgres 11 FWIW...

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Add an `ALIAS` onto the subquery,

```
SELECT  COUNT(made_only_recharge) AS made_only_recharge
FROM    
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT (identifiant) AS made_only_recharge
        FROM cdr_data
        WHERE CALLEDNUMBER = '0130'
        EXCEPT
        SELECT DISTINCT (identifiant) AS made_only_recharge
        FROM cdr_data
        WHERE CALLEDNUMBER != '0130'
    ) AS derivedTable                           -- <<== HERE
```

Comment: @JohnWoo thanks for this, but why is it needed (I guess I'm asking a theory question here)?

Comment: @AndrewCassidy You have to define so you will be able to add further constraints on your query (WHERE derivedTable.<attribute> = 5). otherwise your db will not know how to refer to the subquery

Comment: @AndrewCassidy It is just unlucky syntax. As long as you are not referencing to that subquery, it does not matter what it's alias is. Personally, I'm using `AS pg_sucks`, meaning "well, here you have some redundant identifier, but you could generate some internally by yourself, damn postgres!" :)

Comment: @Tregoreg My aliases always involve some sort of expletive to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

For people able to upgrade to the most recent version, **as of PostgreSQL 16 providing an alias for subqueries is optional**.

[Here's the patch](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=bcedd8f5fce0b69970cf0cee7bca560833d05869) where this was introduced.

And [a blog post](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-waiting-for-postgres-16-subquery-alias-optional) that goes into more detail on the change.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of nested tables, some DBMS require to use an alias like MySQL and Oracle but others do not have such a strict requirement, but still allow to add them to substitute the result of the inner query.

Comment: Your wording suggest there **is** such a requirement for both Oracle and MySQL. Am I reading it right?

Comment: @Scratte I think you're right and the wording is turned around. "MySQL and Oracle but others" should be "Postgresql, but other ssuch as MySQL and Oracle" I think. Of course it's still a run-on sentence, and could be further improved. The 2013 answer is fine and this answer adds nothing (comment on the 2013 answer if you must), so the latter should be removed.

Comment: mysql does require aliases