# MySQL subquery quirk or expected behaviour?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to gain more knowledge concerning the MySQL database and I'm hoping someone over here might be able to explain to me the following issue as I cant find much about this particular behavior anywhere:

This works:

```
SELECT justaname FROM (SELECT productName AS justaname FROM kclbs_products) sdfsdfsd
```

While this doesnt:

```
SELECT justaname FROM (SELECT productName AS justaname FROM kclbs_products)
```

This really puzzle's me and I believe it to be a quirk because whatever I turn the string 'sdfsdfsd' into doesn't matter, the query still works, even when its just a single character (or a very large sequence of characters for that matter). This 'issue' doesn't represent a problem to me currently but I would really like to know the 'why' behind it to be able to deal with this kinda behavior anywhere in the possible future should I ever have to.

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
Two users have helped providing me with the answer to my question, so its solved, and thanks!

Comment: Why are you confused?

Answer (score 2):

It subquery name

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
```

Here is reference from mysql docs
The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM clause must have a name. Any columns in the subquery select list must have unique names.

For futher info use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Comment: I will make use of those documents from here on, thank you for taking the time and trouble to point me to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to MySQL, and its a rule in all DBMS's. if you use subquery in FROM clause you must alias it.

When you write something after subquery (like sdfsdfsd), DBMS consider it as **alias name** of table derived from subquery.

You can see some information about subqueries in `FROM` clause in:

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

and

2. http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/subquery-in-from-clause.php
3. it also explained in [subquery in FROM must have an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias)

Comment: Yes thank you very much as well, your help is appreciated.