# Significance of random letter at the end of sub-query in FROM clause - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have finally succeeded in summing the results of two sql sum queries.  One small step for this guy:)

My question relates to the last character in the code (Z):

```
SELECT SUM(hr)
FROM   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS hr
        FROM   Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database
        WHERE  account_name LIKE 'concessions'
        UNION
        SELECT SUM(amount) AS hr
        FROM   Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database
        WHERE  account_name LIKE 'salaries')Z
```

The code won't work unless there is something following the closing parenthesis).

I'm just curious why that is and why does there need to be a character following the ).

It seems that it doesn't matter what the character is, the code will work.  But the code breaks if I leave it blank.

Thank you

Comment: It's the alias of the subquery. Basically, the result set needs to be identified, so needs an identifier: an alias.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subquery in FROM must have an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias)

Comment: BTW There are a few issues there. Why are you using `LIKE` without a wildcard? That is clearer expressed as `=`. Why is this two queries at all? You could just do `where account_name in ('concessions', 'salaries')` - you want `UNION ALL` not `UNION`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(hr) 
FROM
(
   Select sum(amount) as hr 
   from Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database 
   where account_name like 'concessions'
   union 
   Select sum(amount) as hr 
   from Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database 
   where account_name like 'salaries'
) z
```

To understand better, look at the above version of your query. It's the *same code*, just reformatted to help illustrate what is happening. If you notice, the parent `FROM` clause retrieves data from a sub-query. In this context, SQL requires the subquery to have a *name* of some kind, and so the `z` is added as an *alias* to meet that requirement. You could put anything you wanted there, but since the name doesn't matter to us a single-letter placeholder is fine.

Just like the following query :

```
select * from table1 as z
```

By the way, you didn't use wildcard in your `LIKE` clause! I think you should re-write the query like below :

```
select sum(hr) from 
(
   Select sum(amount) as hr from Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database 
   where account_name like '%concessions&'
   union all
   Select sum(amount) as hr from Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database 
   where account_name like '%salaries%'
) AS z
```

If you don't want to use wildcard, then you should avoid using `LIKE` Use `IN` instead and re-write to this simple one :

```
Select sum(amount) from Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database 
where account_name in('concessions', 'salaries')
```

Comment: @jarlh If you want to improve the query, get rid of the UNION entirely and just do an `IN('concessions', 'salaries')`. But this isn't about improving the query. It's about explaining the alias.

Comment: The where condition can't prevent same sum from first and second select... UNION ALL is necessary.

Comment: Oh, and leading wildcards (ie: `LIKE ('%concessions')` are almost always a bad idea. They remove any possibility of index use on that field and are very slow to evaluate. If he's getting the data he wants from `LIKE 'concessions'`, he can change to `= 'concessions'`, but adding the wildcard will make things worse, rather than better.

Comment: What's the expected result if an account_name 'concessions and salaries' would exist?

Comment: @jarlh He was doing an exact match (no placeholders in the LIKE condition), so it wouldn't count with the original, either.

Comment: I think we could stop discussing on improving the query, he was just need of getting clarification why he was getting error on removing the ending `Z` in his query and i believe he got his answer now :)

Comment: Just one more note on coding style, with `select` and `from` on the same line. Most conventions want all of the top-level sql keywords -- `WITH`, `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, and (arguably) `HAVING` -- to each begin their own line.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as hr
FROM Try_again.dbo.tuesday_practice_database
WHERE account_name IN ('concessions', 'salaries')
```

The existing code has a bug, where it will consolidate your two SUM()s if they are both the same amount. You could also fix this with `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`, but since the `LIKE` conditions don't have any placeholders like `%` or `_` we can do better and simplify this whole thing down to just one `IN()` condition, with no need for any subqueries.

Now, if you wanted to allow more variance in your matches ( ie `LIKE '%concessions%'` and `LIKE '%salaries%'`), then the `UNION ALL` is more helpful... just be warned that leading `%` placeholders in a `LIKE` condition are *very bad* for performance, and should be avoided when possible. Often this means changing the schema in some way, such as adding a table named something like `AccountCategories` that group each account into a specific category that you can target exactly in your query.

But all of that side-steps the actual question: what is that `z` character?

In this case, it's an **alias**. You're using a subquery to union the two smaller queries together. In certain contexts, the SQL language requires subqueries to have a name. This includes using the subquery (derived table) as the target of a `FROM`, `JOIN`, or `APPLY` expression. You can use any name you want — it doesn't matter to the functioning of the query, since it's never referenced again — and so a simple single-letter placeholder, like `z`, is good enough.