# SQL subquery fails in Spark 2 when loading PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

I am facing a very annoying PSQL issue when trying to load part of a PostgreSQL table via a subquery.

The query is :

```
SELECT 
    N1,
    N2, 
    N3,
    N4
FROM CORR 
WHERE CORR_N5 >= (now() - interval '18 year') 
AND CORR_N5 <= (now() - interval '18 year' + interval '1 month')
```

This one works if written directly in PgAdmin. However when I run it from a spark 2 job, I get tho following error message :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
  Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

Even when I put an alias after all the clauses, the same issue happens.

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Melvin, have a look at the below links

https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/app-errors/U115

[subquery in FROM must have an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT N1, N2, N3, N4 
    FROM CORR WHERE COR_N5 >= (now() - interval '18 year') 
    AND CORR_N5 <= (now() - interval '18 year' + interval '1 month')
) AS input
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mansoor, my issue was solved by your input and a simple upgrade of my postgre driver's version. Have a great weekend. Melvin