# Query execution error: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Tags: sql, alias

When a query is completed and executed, query execution errors are sometimes encountered as shown below.

> ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
>   LINE 2: from (
>   ^
>   HINT: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

What's the difference between writing a "as foo" in the subquery and not writing it?

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subquery in FROM must have an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias)

Comment: Simply because its a derived table, not all DB require this. It doesnt matter if you add the `as` or not, *but* it has to be named in sql (because its enforced) even if you are not using it...

Answer (score 1):

## Your Query should be like this ##

```
 Select * from (Select * from tblTest) V --V is an alias
```