# multiple condition in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table dir having directors

```
insert into dir values ('d1','mov1','us',3);
insert into dir values ('d1','mov1','ind',3);
insert into dir values ('d2','mov2','uk',4);
insert into dir values ('d2','mov3','ind',3);
```

want those only which are present in all three us ,ind and uk.

my code:

```
select  directornaame from (
     Select Distinct directornaame, country
       From
       dir
       Where country = 'ind' or country='uk' or country='us'
) as  s
Group By directornaame
Having count(directornaame)>=2
```

but it is should not give any result but it is giving both d1 and d2 in output window.

THanks!!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332890/using-max-and-count-with-having)? Why `>= 2` and not `>= 3`? since you say `"are present in all three us ,ind and uk"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using MAX() and COUNT() with HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332890/using-max-and-count-with-having)

Comment: count on group by colunn is 1, you should count country, and @Sami is right...

Comment: problem is finding directors who are present in all three us ,ind and uk. and in data no one fulffills this condition

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY directornaame HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT country) >=3`

Comment: it works but is there any workaround where we hard code the values of country

Comment: @Adi You could pass a table-valued parameter.

Comment: ok but is also using the same logic, anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple query, no need for `DISTINCT` in the SubQuery and no need for a SubQuery at all

```
SELECT DirectorName
FROM Dir
WHERE Country IN('UK', 'IND', 'US') 
GROUP BY DirectorName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Country) = 3;
```

> it works but is there any workaround where we hard code the values of country

You could use a Table-Valued parameter as

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Country VARCHAR(3));

INSERT INTO @T(Coutry) VALUES
('UK'), ('IND'), ('US');

SELECT DirectorName
FROM Dir
WHERE Country IN(SELECT Country FROM @T) 
GROUP BY DirectorName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Country) = 3;
```