# Another SQL question that has me stumped. Does this require a self-join?

Tags: sql

Here's the question from an interview I'm prepping for...

Given a table messenger_sends:
date | ts | sender_id | receiver_id| message_id | has_reaction

Q: how many unique conversation threads are there ?

I'm not even sure where to start!!

Comment: Possibly just send-receiver pairs?

Comment: `select count(*) from (select sender_id, receiver_id from T where sender_id < receiver_id union select receiver_id, sender_id from T where receiver_id < sender_id) t` You'd have to do both ways since the conversation may only go one direction.

Comment: `select count(*) from (select distinct case when sender_id < receiver_id then sender_id else receiver_id end s, case when sender_id < receiver_id then receiver_id else sender_id end r from T) t`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bf33939d895ed006f375c6233053d6a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution

> ```
> create table table_name (sender_id int, receiver_id int);
> insert into table_name values
> (1,2),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3);
> ```

> ```
> select count(ids)
> from
> (select distinct case when sender_id < receiver_id 
> then concat(sender_id ,receiver_id) 
> else concat(receiver_id, sender_id) end ids
> from table_name) sub_query;
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |                2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63fa4fc2461d3797fc4127d09bc88aba)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clearly explained. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, love the fiddle website. Great tool!

Comment: thanks Kendle. 
Quick follow-up SQL question...why is the "sub_query" alias required? Has always confused me.

Comment: See this post for an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767209/subquery-in-from-must-have-an-alias

Comment: thanks Kendle. You are too kind and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of distinct {sender, receiver} sets -- not pairs because the order is not important.

For me this translates into:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a, b
    FROM (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN sender_id ELSE receiver_id END AS a, -- the smaller id
            CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN receiver_id ELSE sender_id END AS b -- the larger id
            FROM Messages
        ) T
) U
```