# MySQL DELETE row ORDER BY COUNT DESC

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I have a table that contains the similarity of every two questions of a test bank.
[image]

This means question_id `6` is 84% similar to question_id `10`.
And there are 12 similar question of question_id `6`.

I just what the most relevant questions, or the top 7 relevant questions.

I have seen [Mysql delete order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382250/mysql-delete-order-by)
and tried:

```
DELETE FROM     exam_relatedquestion
WHERE
    `exam_relatedquestion`.id IN (
        SELECT
            `exam_relatedquestion`.id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT  `exam_relatedquestion`.id
                FROM    `exam_relatedquestion`
                GROUP BY
                    `exam_relatedquestion`.from_question_id_id
                ORDER BY
                    `exam_relatedquestion`.similarity DESC
                LIMIT 7
            ) a
    )
```

But the error message is:

> [Err] 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause
>   and contains nonaggregated column 'den.exam_relatedquestion.id' which
>   is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How can I delete any rows that are not the top 7 relevant of a question?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` in the first place?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to see questions in Group by `from_question_id_id` and then preserve the top relevant in it. But I don't know what is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work.  Your pseudo-code is not correct anyway, because the sort is in the wrong direction.

In any case, you can use variables to enumerate the questions, and then use `join`:

```
delete erq
    from exam_relatedquestion erq join
         (select erq2.*,
                 (@rn := if(@q = erq2.from_question_id_id, @rn + 1,
                            if(@q := erq2.from_question_id_id, 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          from exam_relatedquestion erq2 cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @q := -1) params
          order by erq2.from_question_id_id, score desc
         ) erq2
         on erq2.id = erq.id
    where rn > 7;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know what does the `erq` mean in my situation. I got `[Err] 1051 - Unknown table 'eqr2'`.