# Using LIMIT on MySql deletion across a two column duplicate

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a large MySql table from which I need to delete duplicates - to qualify as a duplicate, a row much match another row on two columns:

```
SELECT * FROM JwDistanceSurnames n1, JwDistanceSurnames n2 
WHERE n1.JwDistanceSurnameId > n2.JwDistanceSurnameId
AND n1.Surname1 = n2.Surname1
AND n1.Surname2 = n2.Surname2
LIMIT 1000;
```

Because it is a large table, I'd like to do it in batches. My understanding is that I ought to be able to use LIMIT to achieve this. However, this does not execute, citing a syntax error:

```
DELETE n1 FROM JwDistanceSurnames n1, JwDistanceSurnames n2 
WHERE n1.JwDistanceSurnameId > n2.JwDistanceSurnameId
AND n1.Surname1 = n2.Surname1
AND n1.Surname2 = n2.Surname2
LIMIT 1000;
```

What's the error? Is it not possible to use this simple approach to batching here?

MCVE:

```
CREATE TABLE `JwDistanceSurnames` (
  `JwDistanceSurnameId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Surname1` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surname2` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JwScore` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JwDistanceSurnameId`),
  KEY `Surname1` (`Surname1`),
  KEY `Surname2` (`Surname2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `JwDistanceSurnames`
(`JwDistanceSurnameId`, `Surname1`, `Surname2`, `JwScore`)
VALUES (null,'williamsom' ,'williamson' ,0.959999999999998);
```

Repeat the insert a few times. Then run the delete. The expected output is a single row, with the given values. Which of the rows kept is not important.

The error is:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'ORDER BY n1.JwDistanceSurnameId     LIMIT 1000' at
>   line 5

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. For further help see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Good point, although adding an order by clause doesn't seem to help this execute.

Comment: What is the syntax error, and realize that most readers won't/can't setup a delete DML test to reproduce your query.

Comment: For the record, the error is: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1000'`

Comment: if it's unimportant which row is retained, this usually points to a more fundamental flaw in your model. It should matter!

Comment: @Strawberry the model is fine. The data that I imported in to it is not ;) In point of fact, retaining the highest JwScore is likely the best idea but none of the duplicates have different values in this field.

Comment: Well, I'd go with the one with the lowest JwDistanceSurnameId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202618/delete-using-left-join-with-limit-in-mysql), it appears that `LIMIT` cannot be used in a `DELETE` statement when more than one table is being referenced.  One trick around this is to use `LIMIT` in a subquery to identify records for deletion, and then join back to the target table:

```
DELETE t1
FROM JwDistanceSurnames t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT n1.JwDistanceSurnameId
    FROM JwDistanceSurnames n1
    INNER JOIN JwDistanceSurnames n2 
        ON n1.JwDistanceSurnameId > n2.JwDistanceSurnameId
    WHERE n1.Surname1 = n2.Surname1 AND n1.Surname2 = n2.Surname2
    ORDER BY <some_column>    -- IMPORTANT! without this you may get random records
    LIMIT 1000
) t2
    ON t1.JwDistanceSurnameId = t2.JwDistanceSurnameId;
```

So the subquery labelled `t2` uses `LIMIT` to identify batches of 1000 records at a time for deletion, and then we use another join to actually label those target records.

Also note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is not really a well-defined thing, because SQL tables are modelled on unordered sets of records.  If you have some business logic determining which order the batches should be deleted, then consider adding an `ORDER BY` clause (unless it truly does not matter, which would seem unlikely to me).

Comment: Thanks for this - it's running but it's causing table locks. I guess that's a different question :)

Comment: Actually `DELETE bar FROM Foo AS bar LIMIT 1` (single aliased table) also produces a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another way for find of dublicates

```
SELECT n.*
FROM JwDistanceSurnames n
JOIN
  (
    SELECT Surname1,Surname2,MIN(JwDistanceSurnameId) min_JwDistanceSurnameId
    FROM JwDistanceSurnames
    GROUP BY Surname1,Surname2
  ) l
ON n.Surname1=n.Surname1 AND n.Surname2=n.Surname2 AND n.JwDistanceSurnameId>l.min_JwDistanceSurnameId
```