# MySQL Delete with JOINS and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I want to DELETE in chunks and hence trying to use LIMIT with JOINS. The below code is not executing throwing errors. There are around 900+ million rows that need to be deleted. This is on MYSQL 5.7 with InnoDB engine

Can someone please help?

```
DELETE a
FROM order_item_custom_data a
JOIN (
         SELECT oicd.* FROM order_item_custom_data oicd JOIN order o
         ON oicd.mfg_id = o.mfg_id AND oicd.catalog_id = o.catalog_id AND
         ocid.catalog_id = o.order_id
         WHERE o.order_date < '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
         ORDER BY oicd.order_item_custom_data_id
         LIMIT 100000;
) b ON a.mfg_id = b.mfg_id;
```

Comment: You can't use LIMIT directly within DELETE when you're referencing multiple tables at the same time...sooner or later it will throw an error. What's  your question ? Is your query taking to long to execute ?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202618/delete-using-left-join-with-limit-in-mysql

Comment: Are you trying to delete orders or items or both?

Comment: when using DELETE with JOIN, put the table name you want to delete from after DELETE: `DELETE a FROM a JOIN b ...`

Comment: I have edited the query with subselect. Please let me know if its correct

Comment: @Nav change `DELETE` to `SELECT` and check yourself