# Not able to delete with LIMIT in mysql join query between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, limit

This is my sql query:

```
DELETE gur
FROM group_master gm
JOIN group_users gu
ON gu.group_id=gm.id
JOIN group_user_roles gur
ON gur.group_user_id=gu.id
WHERE gm.school_code = 14741359 AND gm.ayid=3
LIMIT 1;
```

I get the error saying there is a syntax error near LIMIT. I found a solution here: [DELETE using LEFT JOIN with LIMIT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202618/delete-using-left-join-with-limit-in-mysql).
I am not able to transform my query into select statements.

Comment: [mre] Put all & only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not at a link. Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only single-table [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) supports LIMIT.

Use your query as SELECT with LIMIT and get ID of the row (remember - LIMIT without ORDER BY is a lottery). Then delete according row from another table copy.

```sql
DELETE group_user_roles 
FROM group_user_roles 
JOIN (SELECT gur.id
      FROM group_master gm
      JOIN group_users gu ON gu.group_id=gm.id
      JOIN group_user_roles gur ON gur.group_user_id=gu.id
      WHERE gm.school_code = 14741359 AND gm.ayid=3
      /* ORDER BY ??? */ LIMIT 1
      ) USING (id)
```

Replace `id` with primary key or unique column/expression for `group_user_roles` table.